# Is there a python library for sparse matrix operations for non-standard algebra-like objects?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

**Summary:** I am looking for a way to do computations with sparse matrices whose non-zero entries are not the usual integers/floats/etc., but elements of an algebra, ie instances of a non-standard python class with addition, multiplication and a zero element.

**It works fine for dense matrices.** I have implemented this algebra by defining a python class `algebra` and overloading addition and multiplication:

```
class algebra(object):
   ...
   __mul__(self,other):
      ...
   __add__(self,other):
      ...
```

`numpy` allows me to define vectors and matrices whose entries are instances of the class `algebra`. It also allows me to perform all the usual operations like matrix multiplication/addition/tensordot/slicing/etc., so it is all working just as for matrices over integers/floats/etc.

**It does not work for sparse matrices.**
To speed up computations, I would now like to replace these dense matrices by sparse ones. I have tried to make this work with SciPy's 2-D sparse matrix package `scipy.sparse`, but I have failed so far. I can populate instances of these sparse matrix classes by my algebra elements, but whenever I do computations with them, I get an error message like

```
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),dtype('O'))
```

To me, this suggests that there is a restriction on the type of objects that are supported by `scipy.sparse`. I do not see any mathematical reason for why the operations for sparse matrices should care about the object type. As long as the class has all the operations of floats, say, it should work. What am I missing? Is there an alternative to `scipy.sparse` which supports arbitrary object types?

---

Below is a **minimal working example**. Note that I have implemented the zero element of the algebra in terms of the usual integer 0. Please also note that the actual algebra I am interested in is more complicated than the real integers!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

class algebra(object): # the algebra of the real integers

    def __init__(self,num):
        self.num = num

    def __add__(self,other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return algebra(self.num+other.num)
        else:
            return self

    def __radd__(self,other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return algebra(self.num+other.num)
        else:
            return self

    def __mul__(self,other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return algebra(self.num*other.num)
        else:
            return 0

    def __rmul__(self,other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return algebra(self.num*other.num)
        else:
            return 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return "algebra:"+str(self.num)  

a=algebra(5)
print(a*a)
print(a*0)
print(0*a)
indptr = np.array([0, 2, 3, 6])
indices = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([a,a,a,a,a,a])
S = csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(3, 3))
print(S)
print("Everything works fine up to here.")
S*S
```

The output is:

```
algebra:25
0
0
  (0, 0)    algebra:5
  (0, 2)    algebra:5
  (1, 2)    algebra:5
  (2, 0)    algebra:5
  (2, 1)    algebra:5
  (2, 2)    algebra:5
Everything works fine up to here.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test", line 46, in <module>
    S*S    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 319, in __mul__
    return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 499, in _mul_sparse_matrix
    data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/sputils.py", line 57, in upcast
    raise TypeError('no supported conversion for types: %r' % (args,))
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'), dtype('O'))
```

I am using Python 3.5.2 on linux.

Answer (score 1):

This may fall more in the comment category, but as an answer I can make it longer, and edit it more.

`numpy` arrays implement object dtype by storing pointers/references to the objects in the array's data buffer.  Math is done by delegating the task to object methods.  The iteration is essentially at Python speeds, comparable to list comprehension (may be even a bit slower).  `numpy` does not do its fast compiled math on these objects.

`scipy.sparse` has not developed this kind of functionality.  A `coo` format matrix can probably be created with the object inputs - but that's because it doesn't do much.  In fact if the `data`, `row` and `col` inputs have the right `numpy` array setup, they are uses as `coo` attributes without change.

Apparently making `csr` as you do with the `indptr` etc also just assigns the attributes.  A `coo` to `csr` conversion might not work so well, since that involves summation of duplicates.

In any case `csr` math code uses a mix of python and c (cython), and the compiled part works with a limited number of numeric types - long and double integers and floats.  I don't think it even works for short ints (`int8`, `int16`).  It does not implement any of the object dtype delegating that `ndarrays` do.

With your `S`:

```
In [187]: S.A                                                                                                
...
ValueError: unsupported data types in input

In [188]: S.tocoo()                                                                                          
Out[188]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.object_'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

no value changes are required for `tocoo`.  But back to `csr` requires summing duplicates:

```
In [189]: S.tocoo().tocsr()                                                                                  
 ...
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)

In [190]: S.tolil()                                                                                          
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/sputils.py:115: UserWarning: object dtype is not supported by sparse matrices
  warnings.warn("object dtype is not supported by sparse matrices")
Out[190]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.object_'>'
    with 6 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

There's no problem in storing this object data

Math with a list of your objects versus an array - similar times:

```
In [192]: alist = [a]*100                                                                                    
In [193]: arr = np.array(alist)                                                                              
In [194]: timeit [i*j for i,j in zip(alist,alist)]                                                           
77.9 µs ± 272 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [195]: timeit arr*arr                                                                                     
75.1 µs ± 2.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

An earlier question, which you may have already seen (I just got an upvote), about using `int16` in sparse matrices.  Same basic issue:

[Why can't I assign data to part of sparse matrix in the first "try:"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046118/why-cant-i-assign-data-to-part-of-sparse-matrix-in-the-first-try)

The symbolics library has a sparse matrix module: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/sparse.html

Pandas has its own sparse Series/Dataframe implementations

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix

> By default when converting to CSR or CSC format, duplicate (i,j) entries will be summed together. This facilitates efficient construction of finite element matrices and the like. (see example)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! What do you mean by "`csr` requires summing duplicates"? I have looked into sympy, but there I cannot even populate the matrix with my algebra elements. I will look into pandas.

Comment: ok, I see. I have now also tried pandas's `SparseDataFrame` and `SparseArray` classes, but both return `TypeError` when I try filling them with algebra objects. As far as I can tell from the documentation, they only support `float`, `int`, `bool`, `datetime64` and `timedelta64`.

Comment: +1 for long comments that explain background. It would be useful if you could summarize your considerable knowhow on scipy.sparse in a blog with tables on what works / what doesn't / a vision for the future (I realize that's not easy).