# How to remove elements different than numbers of a Scipy Sparse Matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a [COO sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) in which every element is a dictionary. I want to filter that matrix by some conditions, nevertheless when I try to multiply the matrix by the filter I get an exception `TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)`. Is it possible to avoid this issue?

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
import numpy as np

row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = [{"x": 1}, {"y": -1}, {"x": -1}, {"x": 2}, {"t": -2}, {"z": 2}]
matrix = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3))

matrix.multiply(np.array([0, 1, 0])) # Raises exception
```

Comment: While it's possible to make such a `coo` matrix, it can't do anything with it.  To do calculations it's converted to a `csr` format matrix, and fails.  Scipy sparse only works with numeric dtypes.

Comment: An object dtype `ndarray` containing dictionaries like this couldn't be used either.  Multiplication is not defined for a dictionary.  `{'x':2}*2` raises an error.

Comment: @hpaulj so it's impossible to filter a matrix with this kind of elements?

Comment: See this other recent SO  https://stackoverflow.com/q/57315454/901925

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to filter a `coo_matrix`, nevertheless it isn't straightforward. First you must create your `filter mask` with `True/False' values and then use it to index the matrix's column, rows and data vectors.

```
In [22]: mask = [True, False, False, True, False, False]

In [23]: matrix.data[mask]
Out[23]: array([{'x': 1}, {'x': 2}], dtype=object)

In [24]: matrix.col[mask]
Out[24]: array([0, 0], dtype=int32)

In [25]: matrix.col[row]
Out[25]: array([0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32)

In [26]: matrix.col[mask]
Out[26]: array([0, 0], dtype=int32)
```